Seaborn plot labeling
Very new to Seaborn...using it in a class and using VSCode to edit notebooks for assignments.
Without uploading a bunch of data here, I have the following code:
myPlot = sns.barplot(dfFrequencies, x="Topic", y="Relative Frequency")
myPlot.set_xticklabels(myPlot.get_xticklabels(), rotation=45)
myPlot.set_title("Pew Poll Responses: Which is Most Meaningful?")

And in VSCode this is the resulting output

So my first question is how can I suppress the circled text?
Later in the same notebook I have the following code:
# Create the requested scatterplot with Mid-Career Year on the x-axis and 
# standardized OPS on the y-axis.
# Remember titles and axis labels.
sns.set(rc={"figure.figsize":(10, 6)})
set_style(theme)
myplot = sns.scatterplot(data=dfHofData, x="Midpoint", y="OPS_z")
myPlot.set_title("Standardized OPS by Mid-Career Year")
myPlot.set_xlabel("Mid-Career Year")
myPlot.set_ylabel("Standardized On Base Percentage Plus Slugging (OPS)")

And it produces this plot.  Again there is the text from the last set but in this case none of them sets have actually done anything.  What am I missing?

The call to set_style(theme) is some code the instructor provided to set the theme to dark mode.  For completeness, here it is:
theme = 'darkmode'
def set_style(theme='darkmode'):
    if theme == 'darkmode':
        sns.set_theme(style='ticks', context='notebook', rc={'axes.facecolor':'black', 'figure.facecolor':'black', 'text.color':'white',
                      'xtick.color':'white', 'ytick.color':'white', 'axes.labelcolor':'white', 'axes.grid':False, 'axes.edgecolor':'white'})
    else:
        sns.set_theme(style='ticks', context='notebook')


You can suppress the output text by adding a semicolon to the end of the line, e.g., myPlot.set_title("Pew Poll Responses: Which is Most Meaningful?");

Alternatively, explicitly capture the output, e.g., _ = myPlot.set_title("Pew Poll Responses: Which is Most Meaningful?")

To supress the output text, either use a ; at the end of the line, e.g.,
myPlot.set_title("Pew Poll Responses: Which is Most Meaningful?");

or explicitly capture the function output:
_ = myPlot.set_title("Pew Poll Responses: Which is Most Meaningful?")

For your other issue, you are using myPlot rather than myplot, i.e., you have a capital P when you shouldn't.
